# cancan - dealing with a HUGE ability.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have a significant Roles aspect to my site and my ability.rb file has grown to a behemoth. It now conducts 25 queries to check 'role' records every time `load_and_authorize_resource` is called. Most of these queries are irrelevant because they govern lots of different permissions other than those relevant to the controller in use.

Let's say if on the `companies` controller, I only want to check permissions for `Company` and `Project`, and I want to ignore `Task`, `Employee`, and `Assignment`.

How can I send parameters to `ability.rb` so it only perform the relevant queries each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, one suggestion could be, that you could define your own ability models for Company and Project.

Something that quickly jumps into mind is the same concept that is being used [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Admin-Namespace).

Perhaps you can override the `current_ability` method in the Company and Project controllers respetively. Something like:

```
def current_ability
  @current_ability ||= CompanyAbility.new(current_user)
end
```

And in your `CompanyAbility` model, that is where you would define your custom permission settings solely for Company.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Christian - what's the link you were referring to on line 2?

Comment: Ooops. Thought I included the URL. Apparently not. See my edit :-)